# Iterating through Hash to output an unordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a Hash where the majority of it is filled with a key with two values associated with the key. There is also another hash within this Hash which is where I've been stuck.

Lets say the hash looks like:

```
{'sports'=>['football', 'basketball'], 'season'=>['summer','fall'], 'data'=>[{'holiday'=>'Christmas', 'genre' => 'Comedy'}, {'holiday'=>'Thanksgiving', 'genre' => 'Action'}]}
```

The output should look like:

```
Sports
  - football
  - basketball
Season
  - summer
  - fall
Holiday
  - Christmas
  - Thanksgiving
Genre
  - Comedy
  - Action
```

So far I have a helper that gives me everything except the `data` section.

```
def output_list_from(hash)
  return if hash.empty?

  content_tag(:ul) do
    hash.map do |key, values|
      content_tag(:li, key.to_s.humanize) +

      content_tag(:ul) do
        # if values.is_a?(Hash)...
        content_tag(:li, values.first) +
        content_tag(:li, values.last)
      end
    end.join.html_safe
  end.html_safe
end
```

This returns the output:

```
Sports
  - football
  - basketball
Season
  - summer
  - fall
Data
  - {'holiday'=>'Christmas', 'genre' => 'Comedy'}
  - {'holiday'=>'Thanksgiving', 'genre' => 'Action'}
```

Which of course makes sense...so I've tried to check in the loop if the `value` is a Hash, but the way it's set up has tricked me. I think it's be easier if I knew what the hash would look like everytime, but it would be a new hash each time. One time there could be a `holiday` within data and the other time there could be both `holiday` and `genre`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: is the array of hashes always in `data`?

Comment: `data` is not *always* in the Hash. if `data` is there, then yes it will be an array of hashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a hash with the correct format. Something like this:

```
hash = {'sports'=>['football', 'basketball'], 'season'=>['summer','fall'], 'data'=>[{'holiday'=>'Christmas', 'genre' => 'Comedy'}, {'holiday'=>'Thanksgiving', 'genre' => 'Action'}]}
formatted_data = hash.dup

data = formatted_data.delete('data')
if data
  data.each do |item|
    item.each do |k, v| 
      formatted_data[k] ||= []
      formatted_data[k] << v
    end
  end
end

puts formatted_data
# => {"sports"=>["football", "basketball"], "season"=>["summer", "fall"], 
# => "holiday"=>["Christmas", "Thanksgiving"], "genre"=>["Comedy", "Action"]}

content_tag(:ul) do
  formatted_data.map do |key, values|
    #... your code here...
  end.join.html_safe
end.html_safe
```

Comment: Impressive. Thanks Uri.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your hash looked like this:

```
hash = { 'sports'=>['football', 'basketball'],
         'season'=>['summer', 'fall'],
         'data1' =>[{ 'holiday'=>'Christmas', 'genre'=>'Comedy'},
                    { 'holiday'=>'Thanksgiving', 'genre'=>'Action' }],
         'data2' =>[{ 'data3'=>[{ 'sports'=>'darts', 'genre'=>'Occult' }] }] 
        }
```

and you wanted a general solution that would work for any number of levels and does not depend on the names of the keys that will not be in the resulting hash (here `'data1'`, `'data2'` and `'data3'`). Here's one way you could do that, using recursion.

**Code**

```
def extract(h, new_hash = {})
  h.each do |k,v|
    [*v].each do |e|
      case e
      when Hash then extract(e, new_hash)
      else new_hash.update({ k=>[e] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov << nv.first }
      end
    end
  end   
  new_hash
end
```

**Example**

```
extract(hash)
  #=> {"sports"=>["football", "basketball", "darts"],
  #    "season"=>["summer", "fall"],
  #    "holiday"=>["Christmas", "Thanksgiving"],
  #    "genre"=>["Comedy", "Action", "Occult"]}
```

**Explanation**

There are, I think, mainly two things in the code that may require clarification.

*#1*

The first is the rather lonely and odd-looking expression:

```
[*v]
```

If `v` is an array, this returns `v`.  If `v` is a literal, the splat operator has no effect, so it returns `[v]`. In other words, it leaves arrays alone and converts literals to an array containing one element, itself. Ergo:

```
[*['football', 'basketball']] #=> ["football", "basketball"]
[*'Thanksgiving']             #=> ["Thanksgiving"]
```

This saves us the trouble of having three, rather than two, possibilities in the `case` statement. We simply convert literals to arrays of one element, allowing us to deal with just hashes and arrays.

*#2*

The second snippet that may be unfamiliar to some is this:

```
new_hash.update({ k=>[e] }) { |_,ov,nv| ov << nv.first }
```

This uses the form of the method [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) that uses a block to resolve the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.  As an example, at some stage of the calculations, `new_hash` will have a key-value pair:

```
'sports'=>['football', 'basketball']
```

and is to be updated with the hash<sup>1</sup>:

```
{ 'sports'=>['darts'] }
```

Since both of these hashes have the key `'sport'`, the block is called upon as arbiter:

```
{ |k,ov,nv| ov << nv.first }
  #=> { |'sport', ['football', 'basketball'], ['darts']| ov << nv.first }
  #=> { |'sport', ['football', 'basketball'], ['darts']|
          ['football', 'basketball'] << 'darts' }
  #=> ['football', 'basketball'] << 'darts'
```

As I'm not using the key `'sport'` in the block, I've replaced that block variable with a placeholder (`_`) to reduce opportunities for error and also to inform the reader that the key is not being used.

<sup>1 I sometimes use darts as example of a sport because it is one of the few in which one can be successful without being extremely physically fit.</sup>

Comment: Impressive as well. Thanks for your time on this @Cary.